# Ajax success function loading div repeatly in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

My ajax code is here,

Success function always shown two times.

If i have two records in database means it will retrieve that two rows on two times, Three row means retrieve two times

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('form#form1').submit(function(e) {
                    var form = $(this);
                    var srpid = form.find('#srpid').val();
                    //$('#cmd_'+srpid).html(" ");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        'type': "POST",
                         url: "<?php echo base_url('pages/post/comments'); ?>",
                        'data': form.serialize(), // <--- THIS IS THE CHANGE
                        //dataType: "html",
                        'success': function(data){
                            $('#cmd_'+srpid).html(data);
                        },
                        //error: function() { alert("Error posting feed."); }
                   });
                  return false;
                });     
            });
            </script>


        <div class="post-scroll" id="cmd_<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
    <?php 
    $command = $this->db->order_by('comment_date','DSC')->where('post_id',$post_id)->get('sr_post_comment')->result();
    foreach($command as $cmd){ 
                    $usercmdview = $this->db->get_where('users',array('id' => $cmd->user_id))->result();
    ?>
     <div class="post-cnt"  style="float:left;">
        <div class="post-img">
             <img src="<?php echo $usercmdview[0]->image; ?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="post-name">
            <p><?php echo $usercmdview[0]->firstname." "; ?><br /><span><?php echo  $cmd->comment_date; ?></span></p> 
        </div>
        <div class="post-cmd">
             <p class="cmdlist_<?php echo $cmd->comment_id; ?>"><?php echo $cmd->comments; ?></p>
        </div>
     </div>
 <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: post relevant html code (there should be 2 html code in your post) 1st the one where it has this javascript code & the 2nd of pages/post/comments

Comment: yes you are correct,.. Thanks. But how to resolve this...

Comment: please update your post with relevant html code.

Comment: i posted my html loading code

Comment: No need to use both `e.preventDefault();` & `return false;` first one is fine;

Comment: Share ajax response it looks like after every ajax call you are sending same html loaded first time that's why the loaded js again binding submit event handler again a& again with every ajax call;

Comment: tried your comments but not solve. again loading two times.. Actually request works single time only but result display two times during loading time only. After refresh it shows single time corectly

Answer (score 0):

You defined an ajax request at "submit" action, but you didn't stop the form submit. It means when you click the "submit" button, the following actions will be done.

1. ajax submit the data to server
2. the form submit also, and it will refresh page.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form#form1').submit(function(e) {
            ...
            return false;
        });     
    });
</script>
```

Comment: DId you use the 'firebug' seeing the response? Did there has two ajax request?